# Issue with SQL Query with Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

```
Table 1
Id(Key) Name
1       XYZ
2       ABC

Table 2
ID(Key) Bank
1       SC
2       CP

Table 3
Id(no key) month year noofduty
1          03     12   20
2          04     12   22
1          03     12   25
2          04     12   15
```

Required Result

```
ID Name Bank TotalDuty
1   XYZ  SC    42
2   ABC  CP    40
```

I am confused with GroupBy in multiple tables, a help is required. using SQL 2000 Server

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [SQL Fiddle with a Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c48e4/1)

```
SELECT t1.id
  , t1.name
  , t2.bank
  , sum(t3.noofduty) as totalduty
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t3
  on t1.id = t3.id
INNER JOIN t2
  ON t2.id = t3.id
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.name, t2.bank
```